# How to split string into array based on every other comma in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following string:

```
"Vortioxetine[1], Imipramine[2], Citalopramasdddd[2], Vortioxetine[1], Imipramine[2], Citalopram[2]"
```

and I want to split it into an array with every other comma, so the result would be an array of

```
[0]Vortioxetine[1], Imipramine[2],
[1]Citalopramasdddd[2], Vortioxetine[1],
[2]Imipramine[2], Citalopram[2]
```

I currently have this code to split it by a single comma:

```
            const pharma = "Vortioxetine[1], Imipramine[2], Citalopramasdddd[2], Vortioxetine[1], Imipramine[2], Citalopram[2]"
            const split = pharma.split(',');
            for(const index in split){ 
                drawText(page, split[index], {
                    ...tableTextBodyCol3 , 
                    x: col6X + 2,
                });
            }
```

You can ignore the drawText area as that is program specific, but I would like it to draw 2 words on the page that I have where as right now it is just doing 1, let me know if other info is needed.

Comment: Try to use `lodash` `chunk` to group splitted strings by 2 strings

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37826698/6243352) or try something like `const arr = s.split(/, */);
    const res = arr.map((e, i) => [e, arr[i+1]]).filter((e, i) => i % 2 === 0);` assuming your array is always even length.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Comment: @Anatoly No this produces a 2d array instead of a grouped 1D array.  I tried to flatten the 2d array the chunk produced however it flattened it completely back into the original string.

Comment: @guitarman You could easily `map` every 2-element inner array into a single string using `twoElementArray.join(', ')`, assuming that the spacing around the commas does not matter.

Comment: @JeffBowman that's what I tried to hint